# Snap store not included in 20.04 live USB

Tags: live-usb, snap

I'm running 20.04 from a live USB. The snap store doesn't seem to be installed. When I tried to install it using the command `sudo snap install snap-store` I got the error

error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/snap-store: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused

How do I get the snap store working?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  (*to get them fixed for upgrades and later releases*)

Comment: Please limit each question to a single issue.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket`

After that use this:

`sudo snap install snap-store`

It is for Graphical-Navigation in Snap-repositories. So, try this:

`/snap/bin/snap-store`
And enjoy!